# Ruby function search bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am having trouble with my search bar function, I want it to search through my recipes model attribute "ingredients". When I put this code in it doesnt give me any results only a blank recipes page after the search. Any help would be great.
I have the ingredients as text inside the recipe table.

this is inside the recipe index.html

```
    <%= form_for "", url: recipes_path, role: "search", method: :get do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term, placeholder: "Seach..." %>
```

<% end %>

this is the recipe controller

```
  def index
  @recipes = Recipe.all
  # @recipes =Recipe.search(params[:search])

  if params[:search]
    @search_term = params[:search]
    @recipes = @recipes.search_by(@search_term)
  end
```

end

this is the recipes model function

```
def self.search_by(search_term)
 where("LOWER(ingredients) LIKE :search_term OR LOWER(title) LIKE :search_term",
 search_term: "%{search_term.downcase}%")
end
```

Also this is the command line when I do the search:

```
Started GET "/recipes?search=chicken" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-07-09 07:52:57 -0400
Processing by RecipesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"search"=>"chicken"}
  Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
  Rendering recipes/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/recipes/index.html.erb:13
  Recipe Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE (LOWER(ingredients) LIKE '%{search_term.downcase}%' OR LOWER(title) LIKE '%{search_term.downcase}%')
  ↳ app/views/recipes/index.html.erb:70
  Rendered recipes/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 5.0ms | Allocations: 2463)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_alerts.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 41)
  Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 11.0ms | Allocations: 7781)
Completed 200 OK in 12ms (Views: 11.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms | Allocations: 8360)
```

Does anyone know why its not searching through the recipes ingredients? Thank you in advance.

Comment: it should be: `Recipe.search_by`, right ? and you could use [form_tag](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag) or [form_with](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_with) instead of `form_for`

Comment: I just changed the model using recipes instead and the form_tag and it still giving me no results, Im wondering why its not rendering anything. the form_with brings an error up so I cant use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpolation in search_by method is wrong.
You wrote `"%{search_term.downcase}%"` when the correct is `"%#{search_term.downcase}%"`. Missed the `#`!

```rb
def self.search_by(search_term)
    where("LOWER(ingredients) LIKE :search_term OR LOWER(title) LIKE :search_term",
    search_term: "%#{search_term.downcase}%")
end
```